# Active election pages are broken network-wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

It appears that all the election pages where an active election is supposed to be underway are broken network-wide

- [Programming Code Golf](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/election) ([PCG Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/election-notification-link-is-broken))
- [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/election)

Sites without an election are working fine

- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election)
- [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/election)
- [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election) (In Nominations)

Comment: [Cooking is fine, though.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Might be related to the phase. Looks like Cooking is only in Nominations. I got a notice to actually vote on PCG and the link is down (but I still got the Caucus badge...)

Comment: No, PPCG's broke earlier today while we were still in the nomination phase. It broke again at the precise moment Cooking's election begun.

Comment: Everything works now!

Comment: @animuson Any insight what did happen here?

Comment: @Johannes I don't know the exact details, but the election code was refactored and there were a few bugs that got introduced.

Comment: As [I wrote on MCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/election-page-is-broken#comment54055_14808), this could hurt the legitimization of the vote. Yes, this is only some internet site, not some nation doing an election. Any plans to do something there? [Carcigenicate suggested](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/election-page-is-broken#comment54056_14808) to send the notification again. You could get a list of the relevant people using the Caucus badge.